# StreamReader issue

Tags: c#, rest

if I put a debuger from starting line one of this code and step through i dont get anything
event after the line

```
    xmlData = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

but if I have debugger on the last line of this code.. where the brace closes, I get everything. i dont know if this only the debuger acting crazy, or a real thing

```
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(context.Request.InputStream))
{
    xmlData = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Can anyone tell me whats going on. cause sometimes i am not able to get any data from streamreader, even though the data is sent correctly.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

The reader isn't going to perform the actual "read" until the ReadToEnd method is called.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: thats not how it is working though. went i step through it.. it doesnt get any data after ReadToEnd() .. Even though i know for sure data has been sent..
it just basic httphandler that captures the request does something with the data and responds back with some data

Comment: Watch out for timeouts.  They may trip when you're debugging.

Comment: thats seems to answer the question .. u have any idea y would be delayed sometimes in normal excution.. there is nothing between request that could be causing this  ..i mean the code is quite straight forward.. and i dont see any firewalls either.. in between .. wen i run a load test of 30000 i get at least 100 to 150 request that show this behavior..

Comment: @user: Change your load test to send fewer requests per second, then see what happens.  You might be knocking the server over.

Answer (score 1):

If you put a breakpoint on a line the break occurs before that line gets executed, so it's no surprise that you don't get any data.

But I suspect what you mean is that you place a breakpoint and then step through the code slowly until you reach the end and then check the contents of the variable and find that they are empty.

- One cause could be a timing issue. It could be that the service you are reading from has **timed out**.
- Another cause could be a **race-condition** in your code.
- One other unexpected thing that can catch people out is that **watches can cause side-effects** and stepping through the code causes the watches to be re-evaluated. This can change the state of your program depending on where you put the break-point. You should be careful not to set up a watch on a property that has a side-effect when evaluated.